# Is $W=\{A \in M_{n\times n}: \det(A)\neq0\}$ a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I prove if two matrices of $W$, say $w_1 ,w_2$, are closed under addition and scalar multiplication. I know that under scalar multiplication $w_1$ is still in $W$ but is there a way to prove
$\det(w_1 + w_2) \neq 0$ ? (knowing that $\det(w_1)\neq 0$ and $\det(w_2)\neq 0$)

Comment: W does not contain the zero vector, so it can't be a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $A = I_n$ the identity $n\times n$ matrix, then $\det (A) = 1 \neq 0$, $\det (-A) = (-1)^n \neq 0$, but $\det(A -A) = \det(0_n) = 0$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we choose the scalar to be $0$.

$$0 \times I = 0$$
We have proven that it is not a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example to reject:

Let $w_1=I_n$ and $w_2=-I_n$, it is vivid that $\det(w_1)$ and $\det(w_2)$ are not zero while $\det(w_1+w_2)=0$.